# Why "absent from school" is "gakkou wo yasumu" when yasumu is intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar

Why "absent from school" is "gakkou wo yasumu" when yasumu is intransitive verb?

Why particle *wo* is used? Why not *ni* or *kara* is used instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

休む{やすむ} is used as both:

- an intransitive verb meaning "to rest", "take a day off" as in 庭｛にわ｝で休む｛やすむ｝
- a transitive verb meaning "to skip", "take a break from", "be absent from" as in the case of 学校｛がっこう｝を休む｛やすむ｝

休む does not have a direct counterpart (with transitive and intransitive usage) in English, however such verbs are quite common. For example you can use the verb "to relax" as intransitive "I need to relax after a workout" and transitive "please relax your arms".